# Which kind of errors are shown in browser: PlayFramework

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.3

I am following the documentation and didn't understand [this](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/JavaRouting) particular paragraph.

> Routes are defined in the conf/routes file, which is compiled. This
>   means that you’ll see route errors directly in your browser:

What does that mean? What kind of errors are shown on browser and what kind doesn't? Are the **compilation errors** shown?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your understanding is correct. The conf/routes file is compiled into an ordinary class. Thanks to that feature, Play framework informs you about some errors both:

- before the application is started - compilation errors,
- during the runtime

For instance, imagine you developed a controller with a method that accepts two parameters and in your route file you passed only one parameter to that method. Play framework will inform you about the mistake so you can fix it before a release.

The same goes for the runtime. If you try to access an URL address that is not defined in the routes file, you will see an appropriate error in you browser about the missing mapping. The same can happen if you try to call an URL mapped with GET using the POST method. Again, Play framework will display a message about the lack of mapping for that method.